Is there support for prescribed, "call-script" like, multi-turn conversations in LangChain?
Often, when building digital assistants and generative AI copilots, you need to implement a conversational flow that gathers information from the user in a prescribed manner and then take some culminating action when all the info has been gathered.  When the amount of information that needs to be gathered is more than just a few things, you need to create a guided conversation where the G-AI solution implements sort of a “call script” that expertly guides the user by prompting them for the information that is required. This prescribed back and forth becomes a multi-turn conversational dialog between the user and G-AI assistant.
Is there direct support for this kind of multi-turn dialog in LangChain?
I am using LangChain's tool capability now but specifying the required info that needs to be gathered as tool arguments does not seem the right approach for rich, multi-turn conversations where the solution may need implement branching behavior based on the responses the users gives along the conversational journey.
I can see using the LangChain Expression Language to code up these types of conversational flows, but...

Is that the best way to approach this?
Is that the only way to approach this?
Have you seen anyone creating a declarative description of a conversation that is then executed by some controller?

Any links you can share on this topic or any ideas/suggestions you might have would be great.
-Russ
